# Number of k-permutations for all k (without replacement)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The formula for the number of ways to select k objects out of n without replacement, is:

$$
^n\operatorname P_k = {n! \over (n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}k!
$$

But what is the sum of this for all $k$ from $0$ to $n$?

$$
P_\mathrm{total} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k!
$$

Can this be turned into a closed formula?

---

EDIT:
Based on hints in the comments, I had a look at the resulting values for small n:

```
n     0  1  2    3          4          5         6         7         8         9         10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
P     1  2  5    16         65         326       1957      13700     109601    986410    9864101    
n!    1  1  2    6          24         120       720       5040      40320     362880    3628800
P/n!  1  2  2.5  2.666667   2.708333   2.716667  2.718056  2.718254  2.718279  2.718282  2.7182818
```

The quotient (third row) looks like it converges towards Euler's number.
Plugging that in as a factor, gives (with rounded values):

```
n     0       1       2       3        4        5         6          7           8            9            10
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
P     1       2       5       16       65       326       1957       13700       109601       986410       9864101
e*n!  2.7183  2.7183  5.4366  16.3097  65.2388  326.1938  1957.1629  13700.1404  109601.1233  986410.1099  9864101.0991
```

Is this the solution then?

$$
P_\mathrm{total} = e \cdot n! \space\space\textrm{rounded down to the nearest integer} \space (\textrm{for} \space n > 0)
$$

Is there a more robust/algebraic way to derive this formula?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The obvious first step is to compute this for small $n$.

Comment: It is very very close to $n!$, but you need to use the gamma definition, and start the integral at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: times $e$, forgot about that. Close to $e \cdot n!$.

Comment: @lulu: OK, I did now.

Comment: Yes, see [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522) and [A007526](http://oeis.org/A007526).

Comment: Try dividing by $n!$.